# Como adicionar valores para propriedades iguais em um objeto

Tags: javascript, array

Gostaria de saber como faço para adicionar valores a uma "propriedade", quando um array apresenta valores diferentes para a segunda "propriedade" e o mesmo valor para a primeira "propriedade".

Por exemplo:

Entrada:

```
array1: {
  {nome: joao, sobrenome: silva},
  {nome: claudio, sobrenome: silva},
  {nome: jose, sobrenome: oliveira},
  {nome: joao, sobrenome: costa}
}
```

Saída:

```
array2: {
  {nome: joao, sobrenome: [silva, costa]},
  {nome: claudio, sobrenome: silva},
  {nome: jose, sobrenome: oliveira}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes criar um objeto novo num ciclo onde iteras os elementos da array inicial. A cada iteração do ciclo podes verificar se o objeto que estás a criar já tem essa chave.

Eu sugiro contudo seres consistente e teres sempre o sobrenome com o tipo Array, assim não precisas verificar mais tarde se é String ou Array.

Eu faria isso assim:

```js
const nomes = [{
    nome: 'joao',
    sobrenome: 'silva'
  },
  {
    nome: 'claudio',
    sobrenome: 'silva'
  },
  {
    nome: 'jose',
    sobrenome: 'oliveira'
  },
  {
    nome: 'joao',
    sobrenome: 'costa'
  }
];

const organizados = nomes.reduce((obj, pessoa) => {
  const nome = pessoa.nome;
  const sobrenomes = obj[nome] ? obj[nome].sobrenome : [];
  return {
    ...obj,
    [nome]: {
      nome,
      sobrenome: [...sobrenomes, pessoa.sobrenome]
    }
  };
}, {});

console.log(organizados);
```

Para fazeres isso como referiste no comentário podes fazer assim:

```js
const nomes = [{
    nome: 'joao',
    sobrenome: 'silva'
  },
  {
    nome: 'claudio',
    sobrenome: 'silva'
  },
  {
    nome: 'jose',
    sobrenome: 'oliveira'
  },
  {
    nome: 'joao',
    sobrenome: 'costa'
  }
];

const organizados = nomes.reduce((obj, pessoa) => {
  const {nome, sobrenome} = pessoa;
  if (!obj[nome]) obj[nome] = {nome};
  obj[nome][sobrenome] = 1;
  return obj;
}, {});
const array = Object.keys(organizados).map(nome => organizados[nome]);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Você poderia me ajudar a entender como as coisas estão acontecendo, principalmente o return? Porque eu quero gerar uma saída diferente que na verdade é assim: array: { {nome:joao, silva:1, costa:1}, {nome:claudio, silva:1}... }, eu preciso saber a quantidade de vezes que o joao apareceu como silva ou outro sobrenome.

Comment: @Magno é sempre melhor colocar na pergunta exatamente o que procuras. Assim não perdes tempo nem quem responde :) Editei a resposta, vê se percebes melhor como funciona e se faz o que procuras...

Comment: Perfeito, Sérgio eu não pergunto exatamente o que eu quero porque eu gosto de tentar resolver o problema, como eu estava com dificuldades em saber como agrupar os sobrenomes perguntei somente isso. Por exemplo, em vez de 1 era para colocar a quantidade de vezes que o mesmo sobrenome apareceu, mas isso eu sei fazer, então fica parecendo que fiz algo tbm, haha. Obrigado.